# Error of conversion Datetime-varchar in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the query I am getting error with:

```
Select Time from Flights where Time <= DATEADD(day,3,'14/05/2018 00:00:00') 
AND Time >= getdate()
```

The error says:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

This error though does not happen if I run the query on a clone-database in SQLExpress (management Studio). Any Idea? Thanks.

Comment: Your Language setting expects MM/DD/YYYY. Change that, and avoid the error or use YYYYMMDD and you should *never* have this error again. [see this blog from Aaron](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: change 14/05/2018 00:00:00 to 05/14/2018 00:00:00

Comment: Best to use the standard format yyyy-mm-dd  or if you must Set DateFormat DMY

Comment: The date 14/05/2018 comes from the calendar component. Should I convert all my dates to YYYYMMDD before I run the query?

Comment: US english uses an awkward format where the month comes before the day, unfortunately many software comes in US english by default. Try to use [ISO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format or change your DB language

Comment: @jean it isn't awkward for those of us who grew up with it. ;) But yes, using the universal standard is the bet way to go.

Comment: @SeanLange It's awkward once you realize there's not a nice ASC or DESC ordering matching a nice "lexical" order like it does with YYYYMMDD. Seriously are not those guy in dark ages thinking in how hard it can become to implement DB collations & formats for many localized formats? =)

Comment: @jean that format is the string representation which has been around far longer than computers. I doubt anybody gave any thought to sort order of date string representation in the 1700s. It doesn't make it awkward for me. I speak dates as MM/DD/YYYY and type them as YYYYMMDD. One is the user consumable version and the other is computer consumable version. Not a big deal at all. :D

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server likes this format (assuming standard latin collation. I can't speak to other lesser used collations):

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

Also, Is your Time column a datetime or is it just time? That could cause another issue.

Try this query and see if it works.

```
Select Time from Flights where Time <= DATEADD(day,3,'2018-05-14 00:00:00') 
AND Time >= getdate()
```